# Different representation matrices for the same linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

My question is about linear transformations and their representation matrices.

Given the matrices $A, B,$ Such that:

$$A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix},
B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a linear transformation $T:R^3 \to R^3$ such that both $A$ and $B$ are the representation matrix of $T?$

I heva no idea how to slve that problem, maybe the answer is yes because the both matrices have the same eigen values?

Is there any other way to get the solution?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: What is your choice of basis?

Comment: There is no basis specified in the question, I think the standard basis.

Comment: I think Fred's answer below is it. The matrix representation always depends on a choice of basis for you domain and co-domain. Without specifying what they are exactly, the answer would also _depend_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_1:=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ be a basis of $V:=\mathbb R^3$ and define the linear mapping $T:V \to V$ by

$T(b_1)=b_1, T(b_2)=2b_2$ and $T(b_3)=3 b_3$.

Then $T$ has the representation matrix $A$.

If $B_2:=\{b_2,b_1,b_3\}$, then the representation matrix of $T$ is $B$

Answer (score 1):

Yes the two matrices are [**similar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) and they represent the same transformation indeed

$$B=P^{-1}AP$$

$$  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$$